# R filling array by rows

Tags: arrays, r

I would like to do some matrix operations and it would be best to utilize 3 (or higher) dimensional arrays.  If I want to fill **matrices** by row there is an argument **(byrow = TRUE**) however there is no such option for creating/filling a multidimensional **array**.  The only way I've been able to accomplish it is by using **aperm** to transpose an array that was filled by column.  For example:

```
arr.1 <- array(1:12, c(3,2,2))

arr.1

arr.2 <- aperm(arr.1, c(2,1,3))

arr.2
```

produces the correct result, a dimension 2,3,2 array that is filled by row.  It seems a bit counter intuitive to have to work backward from a Column x Row x Range array to get to a Row x Column x Range array.  This might be bad habits from previous f77 coding or have I overlooked something simple?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in R are filled in by *traversing the first dimension first*. So first the first dimension is traversed, then the second dimension, and then third dimension if it is available.

In case of a matrix:

```
array(c(1,2,3), dim = c(3,3))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
```

Or with assignment:

```
M <- array(dim = c(3,3))
M[,] <- c(1,2,3)
M

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
```

Assigning to the second dimension is easy:

```
M <- array(dim = c(3,3))
M[,2:3] <- c(1,2,3)
M

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    1    1
[2,]   NA    2    2
[3,]   NA    3    3
```

But assigning to first dimension is more tricky. The following doesn't give the expected result:

```
M <- array(dim = c(3,3))
M[2:3,] <- c(1,2,3)
M

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    2    1    3
```

Data is filled by first traversing the first dimension, then second. What we want is to first traverse the second dimension, then first. So we have to [`aperm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/aperm.html) the array (or transpose in case of matrix).

```
M <- array(dim = c(3,3))
Mt <- aperm(M)
Mt[,2:3] <- c(1,2,3)
M <- aperm(Mt)
M

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    3
```

There are maybe more elegant ways to do the last which I am not aware of.

Comment: This solution works for 2-dimensional matrices. However, for 3-dimensional arrays with unequal dimension sizes (e.g., a 3 x 2 4 x 5), the permutation of dimensions does not replace the items at the desired place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interpret a vector of values as an n-dimensional array in "row-major order" (as in C, or more precisely, last dimension varying fastest), you can use function [array2() from package *listarrays*](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/listarrays/html/array2.html). This is the logical extension of `matrix(..., byrow = TRUE)` to multiple dimensions.

Compare base R

```
> (a <- array(1:24, c(2,3,4)))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    9   11
[2,]    8   10   12

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   15   17
[2,]   14   16   18

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   19   21   23
[2,]   20   22   24
```

with

```
> library(listarrays)
> (a <- array2(1:24, c(2,3,4)))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]   13   17   21

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    6   10
[2,]   14   18   22

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    7   11
[2,]   15   19   23

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    8   12
[2,]   16   20   24
```

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation would be to "teach" yourself the default order by running

`foo<- array(1:60,3,4,5)` 
Then you can fill an arbitrary array either by rearranging your source vector or by creating matrices and loading them into the z-layers of the array in the order desired.

Comment: This is not really a response, but a call to change the OP question...