# Fill multidimensional array by row

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multidimensional-array, vector

Before presenting the question, I will point out that something similar was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409209/r-filling-array-by-rows) but that this thread doesn't really answer my question.

Consider the following dimensional arrays:

```
 1D: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
 2D: [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]]
 3D: [[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], [[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]]
 4D: [[[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[[9,10],[11,12]], [[13,14],[15,16]]]]
 ...
```

- The 1D array is length 16
- The 2D array is 2x8
- The 3D array is 2x2x4
- The 4D array is 2x2x2x2

Suppose I want to create the arrays. For the first two, I could do something like this in R

```
oneD <- array(1:16, dim=16) # class(oneD) = array
twoD <- array(1:16, dim=8) # class(twoD) = matrix
```

However, the twoD array is now represented as

```
[[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15], [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]]
```

I am aware of two ways around this.

```
twoD <- aperm(array(1:16, dim=8))
twoD <- matrix(1:16, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

However, these methods won't work for filling the 3D and 4D arrays. I fill them below, but I would like them to match my definitions above.

```
threeD <- array(1:16, dim=c(2,2,4)) # class(threeD) = array
fourD <- array(1:16, dim=c(2,2,2,2)) # class(fourD) = array
```

**EDIT**

bgoldst's answer made me realize that in fact aperm does work for what I want.

```
threeD <- aperm(array(1:16, dim=c(2,2,4))
# threeD[1,1,1] = 1
# threeD[1,1,2] = 2
# threeD[1,2,1] = 3
# threeD[1,2,2] = 4
# threeD[2,1,1] = 5
# ....
```

Comment: Are these called arrays? These seem more like trees from the way they're structured.

Comment: Also, maybe something with `length()` can help you?

Comment: You seem to be thinking with a row-dominant mind set. If working with R you should think of matrix and array construction as column-oriented,

Comment: Your constructions with R are _not_ delivering what you think they are. You should print them out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you've written your data, you need to fill your arrays across the deepest dimension first, and then across shallower dimensions. This is the opposite of the way R normally fills matrices/arrays.

It also needs to be said that this is slightly different from simply filling *by row*. To use your 3D array as an illustration of this, you've indicated it requires 4 z-slices, and the innermost "subarrays" have length 4. This means you need to fill across z-slices first, then across columns, then across rows. This is not merely filling *by row*, but by deepest dimension to shallowest dimension (or greatest to least, if you prefer). Admittedly, this concept is often referred to as "by row" or "row-major order", but I don't care for those terms, since they're too 2D, and they're also misleading IMO, since rows are considered to be the shallowest dimension.

To elaborate: It's better to think of fill order as being *across* dimensions rather than *along* dimensions. Think of an *r*×*c*×*z* cube. If you're facing the front of the cube (that is, facing the *r*×*c* matrix formed from *z* = 1), if you move *along* row *r* = 1, that is, from left to right along the top row, then you're also moving *along* (or *within*) z-slice *z* = 1. The idea of moving along a dimension is not helpful. But if you think of such left-to-right movement as being *across* columns, then that is completely unambiguous. Thus, across rows means up-down, across columns means left-right, and across z-slices means front-back. Another way of thinking about this is each respective movement is along the dimension "axis", although I don't usually like to think of it that way, because then you have to introduce the idea of axes. Anyway, this is why I don't care for the terms "by row" and "row-major order" (and similarly "column-major order"), since the proper way to think about that movement (IMO) is *across columns* for 2D, or across the deepest dimension (followed by shallower dimensions) for higher dimensionalities.

You can achieve the requirement by first building the arrays with reversed dimensionality, and then transposing them to "dereverse" (?) the dimensionality. This will lay out the data as you need. Of course, for 1D, no transposition is necessary, and for 2D we can just use [`t()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html), but for higher dimensionalities we'll need [`aperm()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/aperm.html). And conveniently, when you call `aperm()` without specifying the `perm` argument, by default it reverses the dimensionality of the input; this is just like calling `t()`.

```
array(1:16,16);
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
t(array(1:16,c(8,2))); ## alternatives: matrix(1:16,2,byrow=T), aperm(array(1:16,c(8,2)))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
## [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
## [2,]    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
aperm(array(1:16,c(4,2,2))); ## same as aperm(array(1:16,c(4,2,2)),3:1)
## , , 1
##
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    5
## [2,]    9   13
##
## , , 2
##
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    2    6
## [2,]   10   14
##
## , , 3
##
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    3    7
## [2,]   11   15
##
## , , 4
##
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    4    8
## [2,]   12   16
##
aperm(array(1:16,c(2,2,2,2))); ## same as aperm(array(1:16,c(4,2,2)),4:1)
## , , 1, 1
##
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    5
## [2,]    9   13
##
## , , 2, 1
##
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    3    7
## [2,]   11   15
##
## , , 1, 2
##
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    2    6
## [2,]   10   14
##
## , , 2, 2
##
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    4    8
## [2,]   12   16
##
```

Comment: Thanks - I appreciated your explanation about the fill order across dimensions and the aperm function was what I was looking for. I didn't realize that R always fills across the shallow dimension first.