# 3D array filled by row in R sorted first from left to right, after descendant

Tags: arrays, r

I need to create a 3D array sorted by row, from left to right and descendent.

```
x <- 100
```

I have tried with this:

```
b <- array(1:96, dim= c(8,4,3))
```

but it sorts firstly descendently.  Using apperm(b) doesn't work as well

The result I want is this:

```
, , 1

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755233/r-fill-multidimensional-array-by-row

Comment: They use apperm but doesn't work in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array` by default fill values along 1st dimension, then 2nd dimension, then 3rd; What you are looking for is fill it in the order of *(2nd, 1st, 3rd)*, you can initialize the array with the shape of 1st dimension and 2nd dimension switched and then use `aperm` on it:

```
b <- aperm(array(1:96, dim= c(4,8,3)), c(2,1,3))
#                             ^ ^        ^ ^   switch the dimension twice here 
b
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My first try, but @Psidom's answer is the right way to do this.

You need to make it as a combination of 3 matrices and then combine them into an array. In the code below I used `96*i/3` to make it flexible for more than 3 matrices  to be combined.

```
b <- array( c( aperm(array(1:(96*1/3), dim = c(4,8))), 
               aperm(array(33:(96*2/3), dim = c(4,8))),
               aperm(array(65:(96*3/3), dim = c(4,8))) ) , 
           dim = c(8, 4, 3))
```

This will be the output:

```
b[, , 1]

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
# [1,]    1    2    3    4 
# [2,]    5    6    7    8 
# [3,]    9   10   11   12 
# [4,]   13   14   15   16 
# [5,]   17   18   19   20 
# [6,]   21   22   23   24 
# [7,]   25   26   27   28 
# [8,]   29   30   31   32
```