# Reshape 2x6 array into 3x2x2, row-wise

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have the following array:

```
set.seed(10)
data <- array(rexp(12), dim=c(2,6))

         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 1.398107 0.1704216 0.1664439 0.01057119 2.3546118 0.5222435
[2,] 1.110459 1.9187813 0.9702900 2.79300971 0.6672384 0.1467129
```

And I want to reshape it, in order to get an array with [3,2,2] dimensions, but doing it by row like this:

```
, , 1

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.398107  0.1704216
[2,] 0.1664439 0.01057119
[3,] 2.3546118 05222435

, , 2

           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.110459   1.9187813
[2,] 0.9702900  2.79300971
[3,] 0.6672386  0.1467129
```

I tried `array(data, dim=c(3,2,2))` but it doesn't do it the way I want to, any ideas?

Comment: Please edit this to fix the seed to correspond to the data.

Comment: Related: [Fill multidimensional array by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755233/fill-multidimensional-array-by-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
The better method is `aperm(array(data, c(2, 2, 3)))`. Thanks @smci for the link.

Original solution:

I get different data with that seed, but you can use `matrix` and `lapply` to make each row a two-column matrix, then `abind` to bind into one array.

```
set.seed(10)
data <- array(rexp(12), dim=c(2,6))
data
# 
# [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
# [1,] 0.01495641 0.7521589 0.2316586 2.3276229 1.2883101 0.4265298
# [2,] 0.92022120 1.5750419 1.0866730 0.7291238 0.6722683 1.1154219

library(abind)
abind(lapply(split(data, row(data)), matrix, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
      , along = 3)

# , , 1
# 
# [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.01495641 0.7521589
# [2,] 0.23165862 2.3276229
# [3,] 1.28831010 0.4265298
# 
# , , 2
# 
# [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.9202212 1.5750419
# [2,] 1.0866730 0.7291238
# [3,] 0.6722683 1.1154219
```

With pipes

```
library(magrittr)
data %>% 
  split(row(.)) %>% 
  lapply(matrix, ncol = 2, byrow = T) %>% 
  abind(along = 3)
```

Here's an option that is much faster and requires no packages. I don't think it's very clear though. Not sure how to write it more clearly.

```
array(unlist(data)[order(rep(c(1, 3, 2, 4), 3))], dim = c(3, 2, 2))
```

Maybe this?

```
array(unlist(data) %>% .[order(!seq_along(.) %% 2
                               , !seq_along(.) %% 4)]
      , dim = c(3, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the probably much faster and simpler  base solution:

```
 array( aperm(data, c(2,1) ), c(3,2,2) )
```

I get a different array for that random seed:

```
data
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.01495641 0.7521589 0.2316586 2.3276229 1.2883101 0.4265298
[2,] 0.92022120 1.5750419 1.0866730 0.7291238 0.6722683 1.1154219
```

The `aperm` function can exchange rows for columns:

```
> aperm(data, c(2,1))
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.01495641 0.9202212
[2,] 0.75215894 1.5750419
[3,] 0.23165862 1.0866730
[4,] 2.32762287 0.7291238
[5,] 1.28831010 0.6722683
[6,] 0.42652979 1.1154219
```

And `array` can then rearrange to the desired structure:

```
>  array( aperm(data, c(2,1)), c(3,2,2))
, , 1

           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.01495641 2.3276229
[2,] 0.75215894 1.2883101
[3,] 0.23165862 0.4265298

, , 2

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.9202212 0.7291238
[2,] 1.5750419 0.6722683
[3,] 1.0866730 1.1154219
```

Comment: Interesting, but the arrangement is a little different than given in the question. e.g. 0.6722 would be in the 3rd row, 1st column of the 2nd (3x2) matrix according to the example output. Definitely seems like there should be an easier way to get the desired output than my answer though.